# Select option problem via Selenium - Unable to locate element error

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am new to Python and Selenium. I couldn't find how to select option on web page.

Website code [Screenshoot of select tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkMjX.png)

```
<div class="col-xs-6 middle">
<select class="form-control select-box hisse" size="1" id="MENKUL_NO" name="MENKUL_NO" style="display: none;">
<option value="" selected="">Seçiniz</option>
<option value="1368">ACSEL-ACIPAYAM SELÜLOZ</option>
<option value="207">ADEL-ADEL KALEMCILIK</option>
</select>

<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single chosen-container-active chosen-with-drop" style="width: 429px;" title="" id="MENKUL_NO_chosen">
<a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
<span>Seçiniz</span>
<div><b></b></div></a>
<div class="chosen-drop">
<div class="chosen-search">
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<ul class="chosen-results">
<li class="active-result result-selected highlighted" data-option-array-index="0" style="">Seçiniz</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1" style="">ACSEL-ACIPAYAM SELÜLOZ</li>
<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2" style="">ADEL-ADEL KALEMCILIK</li>
</ul></div></div></div>
```

I try this but doesn't find element  `Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MENKUL_NO"]')).select_by_value(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select_by_value("ADEL-ADEL KALEMCILIK") or
select_by_index(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But doesnt work. İn webpage there is a select tag and also display is none in html. After that code there is div blocks to select option. I delete display style in select tag and then I select option on div blocks. İt select option in select tag also (Sorry for English)

Comment: can you share the url or html of the select tag

Answer (score 0):

First, try a different locator for the main element, as even id may be not unique.
Afterwards, try finding by index.

```
locator =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@class="form-control select-box hisse"]')
select = Select(locator)
select.select_by_index(1)
```

Also, try selecting by value:

```
select.select_by_value('1368')
```

Value is dropdown option value which is 1368 or 207. The first option does not have a value. If you want to select the first element, use `select_by_index(1)`
Or, use:

```
select.select_by_visible_text('Seçiniz')
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But doesnt work. İn webpage there is a select tag and also display is none in html. After that code there is div blocks to select option. I delete display style in select tag and then I select option on div blocks. İt select option in select tag also (Sorry for English)

Comment: Try adding time.sleep(3) before selecting a dropdown and before selecting and option. For this `import time`. This is foe debugging. Also, I've updated my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I see that it is select and option tag in HTML. You can use the below code with Explicit wait.

```
select = Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[id='MENKUL_NO'][name='MENKUL_NO']"))))
select.select_by_visible_text('ACSEL-ACIPAYAM SELÜLOZ')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I found there is a frame tag. that is why it couldnt find.

```
browser.switch_to_frame("ifr")
```

with this code. I accomplish my task.

Thank you all who responses

Comment: That is the reason you should always share stacktrace and bit more html